# There's no line here to end

Tags: errors, environments

I'd just defined a command, as below:

```
\newcommand{\Question}[1]{\textbf{?: #1}\\[5pt]}
```

Here is the snippet, in that I want to use an **itemzie** environment:

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\Question}[1]{\textbf{?: #1}\\[5pt]}

\begin{document}

\section*{Question \#2}
\Question{Here is the question
\begin{itemize}
    \item[2.1] first part
    \item[2.2] second part
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

The compilation raises an error, as:

> There's no line here to end.

So, as I add a character just at the end of the **itemize** environment, the error will be disappeared:

```
\Question{Here is the question
\begin{itemize}
    \item[2.1] first part
    \item[2.2] second part
\end{itemize}
.
}
```

Seemingly, the definition of **Question** command should be changed, but I don't know how I should do that.

Comment: the posted code does not make the error that you ask about but `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.` which is a different message because of a different error, which did you want to ask about?

Comment: Use `{\bfseries#1}` instead of `\textbf{}`. But i find a bit weird to have the whole uestion bold faced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I just made a mistake to reflect the error type. Please find the applied edit.

Comment: Add vertical spaace using `\vspace{5pt}`.

Comment: I think an environment for the questions would be much better than a command.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I did consider `\vspace{5pt}` but the error has not been resolved.

Comment: It is certainly resolved for the given code. If i change to bfseries and vspace, no error at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole construct would certainly be better as an environment. `\textbf` does not allow blank lines (which relates to an earlier version of the question) and use of `\\` is almost never wanted outside tables. here if `#1` does not end mid-paragraph then you will get an error from `\\` saying that there is no line to end, you should use `\par\vspace{5pt}` or better use a display environment based on `list` so that space from adjacent displays is better handled.

But a simple redefinition would be

```
\newcommand{\Question}[1]{{\bfseries?: #1\par\vspace{5pt}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that a command is useless here. And the manual numbering will drive you insane. Put it in a nice environment and let LaTeX do the job.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\newcounter{question}
\newenvironment{question}{\refstepcounter{question}\section{Question \thequestion}\bfseries{?:~}}{\par\vspace{5pt}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{qitemize}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[qitemize]{label={\thequestion.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}What is a cool animal?
    \begin{qitemize}
        \item first wombat
        \item second capybara
    \end{qitemize}
    \end{question}
\begin{question}What is a tasty fruit?
    \begin{qitemize}
        \item Banana
        \item Lemon
    \end{qitemize}
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image: roboticistNoLineToEnd]

Personally, i consider the whole question bold as *extremely* ugly.

Comment: +1 for saying what he should do rather than why what he did gave an error (although I seem to have the tick for doing the latter, sorry:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I saw your answer with the explanations. No need to double it. And it was accepted before i decided to post. I thought about making it CW, but ...

Comment: @Johannes_B: I wish I could mark this answer as the accepted, as well. Thanks for the presented points and improvements.